R: tablas cruzadas de porcentaje ponderados con las variables en las filas y sus valores en las columnas
Estoy usando el paquete expss para generar una tabla cruzada de porcentajes ponderados de cinco variables categóricas de escala tipo Likert y una dicotómica a partir de una data frame proveniente de una encuesta.
Las cinco variables categóricas poseen los mismos valores en una escala Likert del 1 al 4.
Inicialmente, lo que deseo obtener como resultado es una tabla que me exprese los porcentajes ponderados de cada valor de las escalas presente en cada variable categórica (Variables según escalas).
La tabla debe verse como una tabla cruzada con las etiquetas de las variables en las filas y las etiquetas de los valores en las columnas. Debe quedarme así:




Ningún día
Algunos días
Más de la mitad
Casi todos los días
No precisa
Sin información




Pregunta 1
54.3
42.0
2.4
1.3
0
0.0


Pregunta 2
46.5
47.8
3.4
2.2
0
0.1


Pregunta 3
70.7
26.9
1.2
1.2
0
0.1


Pregunta 4
73.8
22.1
2.2
1.7
0
0.2


Pregunta 5
51.2
41.3
4.4
3.0
0
0.2



He empleado el siguiente código que adapté de otro post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611802/21955095):
Df<-Data_p|>
  #mutate(acrosP7_1:P7_5, TIPO_INFORMANTE, fe_ajust_doc_dirs(C(P7_1, P7_2, P7_3, P7_4, P7_5)))|>
  select(P7_1:P7_5)|>
  mutate(across(c(P7_1:P7_5),
                ~ tidyr::replace_na(., 100)))|>
  mutate(across(c(P7_1:P7_5), ~labelled(., labels = c("Ningún día" = 1,
                                                      "Algunos días" = 2,
                                                      "Más de la mitad" = 3,
                                                      "Casi todos los días" = 4,
                                                      "No precisa" = 99,
                                                      "Sin información" = 100))))|>
  apply_labels(P7_1 = "Pregunta 1",
               P7_2 = "Pregunta 2",
               P7_3 = "Pregunta 3",
               P7_4 = "Pregunta 4",
               P7_5 = "Pregunta 5")

res = Df
for(each in colnames(Df)){
    res = res %>% 
        tab_cells(total(label = "|")) %>% # suppress total label 
        tab_cols(unvr(vars(each))) %>%  # remove variable label 
        tab_stat_rpct(total_row_position = "none", label = var_lab(vars(each))) # use variable label as statistic label
}

res = res|>
  tab_pivot()|>
  if_na(0)|>
  tab_caption("Síntomas")

El problema que tengo es que puedo agregar otras variables en la base que usará para el código, como el factor de ponderación o una variable dicotómica para dividir los casos, porque el each en el código hace que la función personalizada ponga los valores de todas las variables seleccionadas en las columnas y saque porcentajes para ellas también. Yo solo deseo que haga este proceso con las 5 variables likert. También quisiera generar otra tabla ponderada que divida cada pregunta según una variable dicotómica como en el siguiente ejemplo :





Ningún día
Algunos días
Más de la mitad
Casi todos los días
No precisa
Sin información




Pregunta 1
A
58.1
38.7
2.0
1.2
0.0
0.0



B
55,2
42,2
1,8
0,7
0,0
0,0


Pregunta 2
A
46,1
47,9
4,2
1,5
0,0
0,3



B
46,0
49,5
2,9
1,6
0,0
0,0


Pregunta 3
A
75,8
22,5
0,5
1,3
0,0
0,0



B
70,4
27,3
1,3
1,0
0,0
0,0


Pregunta 4
A
78,7
18,0
0,7
2,7
0,0
0,0



B
74,0
21,6
3,3
0,8
0,0
0,3


Pregunta 5
A
57,6
39,5
1,4
1,5
0,0
0,0



B
51,4
39,5
5,6
3,5
0,0
0,1



Como podría modificar el código de arriba para obtener los resultados que espero.

Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y visitar el centro de ayuda para ir aprendiendo sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo.
